# Issues with code C#

Tags: c#, wpf

Here is my code:

```
 private void Instalarbtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        string MinecraftFolder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + "/.minecraft";        
        string destinationFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "system.zip");

        FastZip FastZip = null;
        if (Directory.Exists(MinecraftFolder + "/temp"))
        {
            Directory.Delete(MinecraftFolder + "/temp", true);
        }
        FastZip.ExtractZip(MinecraftFolder + "/bin/minecraft.jar", MinecraftFolder + "/temp/Minecraft", String.Empty);

        try
        {
            Directory.Delete(MinecraftFolder + "/temp/Minecraft/META-INF", true);
        }

        catch (DirectoryNotFoundException e1)
        {

        }
        FastZip.ExtractZip(destinationFile, MinecraftFolder + "/temp", String.Empty);
        FastZip.CreateZip(MinecraftFolder + "/bin/minecraft.jar", MinecraftFolder + "/temp/Minecraft", true, String.Empty);

        if (Directory.Exists(MinecraftFolder + "/temp"))
        {
            Directory.Delete(MinecraftFolder + "/temp", true);
            MessageBox.Show("Instalado correctamente", "Instalador");
        }



    }
```

(Sorry for the long code)

If helps i´m trying to extract a .jar, add content at the same folder and repack again.

It doesnt works

Anyone knows because don´t works?

And if know the solution, please tell me

Thanks

EDIT: With this code i want unzip all folders from minecraft.jar, then add some files with overwrite the files  and repack again

Comment: "It doesnt works" what is the _exact_ problem?

Comment: "It doesnt works" isn't even slightly enough information. What happens compared with what you wanted to happen? What diagnostics have you performed so far?

Comment: Have you tried to Debug your code step by step? What error messages do you get (if any)?

Comment: There are *tons* of videos on youtube about how to patch minecraft in a safe way.

Answer (score 2):

Please be more specific...

Change this and debug, try to see the error description of the exception:

```
catch (Exception e1)
{
    MessageBox.Show(e1.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you're not specific about your problem, I'll choose the first issue I see:

```
string destinationFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "system.zip");
```

You might not have write permissions for the directory this will refer to. This could be one cause of failure. Run your application as administrator, or change the directory you will write to, and if that works, this may very well be your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have to create a new instance of FastZip, you're currently assigning null to it.

```
FastZip FastZip = null;
```

Replace with:

```
FastZip FastZip = new FastZip();
```

I recommend you change your `FastZip` instance's name also (currently called `FastZip` to more easily recognizable `fastZip` to distinct it from calling FastZip's (possible) static methods instead of the methods of the actual instance.

```
FastZip fastZip = new FastZip();
```

Answer (score 1):

The tag shows C#.

If so, your folder separators are wrong.

If in doubt, use Path.Combine.

Here's a version using that (and a few extra variables, so the code is easier to read):

```
private void Instalarbtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {

  string appFolder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
  string MinecraftFolder = Path.Combine(appFolder, "minecraft");
  string destinationFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "system.zip");

  FastZip FastZip = null;
  string minecraftTemp = Path.Combine(MinecraftFolder, "temp");
  if (Directory.Exists(minecraftTemp)) {
    Directory.Delete(minecraftTemp, true);
  }
  string minecraftBin = Path.Combine(MinecraftFolder, "bin");
  string minecraftTempMinecraft = Path.Combine(minecraftTemp, "Minecraft");
  FastZip.ExtractZip(minecraftBin, minecraftTempMinecraft, String.Empty);
  string minecraftTempMinecraftMETAINF = Path.Combine(minecraftTempMinecraft, "META-INF");
  try {
    Directory.Delete(minecraftTempMinecraftMETAINF, true);
  } catch (DirectoryNotFoundException e1) {

  }
  FastZip.ExtractZip(destinationFile, minecraftTemp, String.Empty);
  string minecraftBinMinecraftJar = Path.Combine(minecraftBin, "minecraft.jar");
  FastZip.CreateZip(minecraftBinMinecraftJar, minecraftTempMinecraft, true, String.Empty);
  if (Directory.Exists(minecraftTemp)) {
    Directory.Delete(minecraftTemp, true);
    MessageBox.Show("Instalado correctamente", "Instalador");
  }

}
```

I have no idea if it works. I do not have or use this FastZip utility, and I did not even bother trying to understand the logic.